# How install Flask correctly for python 3.7 to run this github project?

Tags: python, web, github, flask

I want to run this Github code on my MacOS:
https://github.com/llSourcell/AI_Startup_Prototype/tree/master/flaskSaaS-master

I have both the latest pip, Python 2.7 and 3.7

I have also installed Flask (for python 3: https://dev.to/sahilrajput/install-flask-and-create-your-first-web-application-2dba )

and made a hello world in PyCharm

I use the given setup instructions from the Github project:
I go to the folder (I have downloaded it and extracted the zip)
than I run the 1st set up code on the terminal:

```
make install && make dev
```

And I get the following message:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: already answered here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the certificate verification. You can try to working around it by adding `pypi.org` (the registry) and `files.pythonhosted.org` (the file storage) as trusted hosts.

Try this:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org Flask==0.10.1
```

The issue may also be fixed by re-installing pip

Comment: I have tried and got: 
```
Collecting Flask==0.10.1
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==0.10.1 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask==0.10.1
```

Comment: You need to add `pypi.python.org` as a trusted host too I guess. Did you try upgrading pip?

Comment: reinstalled pip than run your code than it works :D